# Next.js 13 with sanity studio unexpected behaviour with layouts

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I am trying to make a bloglike application using next.js 13 and sanity for the CMS.
I have created a navbar that I would like to only show on the standard page but not on the stanity studio page. The app looks as it should on initial load, however, if I navigate to the /studio the nav is there. If I then go back to the app using a navigation button the page loads but without the navbar. Here is the folder structure from the app directory.

```
|   head.tsx
|
+---(admin)
|   |   layout.tsx
|   |
|   \---studio
|       \---[[...index]]
|               head.tsx
|               loading.tsx
|               page.tsx
|
\---(user)
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx
```

Here is the app(user)\layout.tsx

```
import Header from '@/components/Header'
import '../../styles/globals.css'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Here is the app(admin)\layout.tsx

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My understanding was that having a layout for the admin and one for the user, the former without the  and the latter with would mean it would only show in one. The documentation for Next.js is a little confused at the moment due to the changes brought in in 13.